# org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body writer has been found

Tags: spring-boot

Below is my Api:-
But after I upgraded my spring boot version from 2.3.x to 3.1.x and cxf from 3.x to 4.x, I am getting error in the return statement.
ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body writer has been found for class com.woorea.openstack.heat.model.Resources, ContentType: application/json

```
@GET
    @Path("/stacks/{stack_name}/{stack_id}/resources")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Resources getStackResources(
            @Parameter(description = "The location id of the openstack site",
                    required = true) @PathParam("cloud_site_id") String cloudSiteId,
            @Parameter(description = "The tenant inside openstack",
                    required = true) @PathParam("tenant_id") String tenantId,
            @Parameter(description = "The stack name", required = true) @PathParam("stack_name") String stackName,
            @Parameter(description = "The stack id", required = true) @PathParam("stack_id") String stackId,
            @Parameter(description = "The Nested Depth to be returned on nested stacks",
                    required = false) @QueryParam("nested_depth") int nestedDepth) {
        try {
            Resources res=heatAdapterUtils.queryStackResources(cloudSiteId, tenantId, stackName + "/" + stackId, nestedDepth);
            return res;
        } catch (MsoCloudSiteNotFound e) {
            logger.error("Cannot find cloud site", e);
            throw new NotFoundException("Cannot find cloud site: " + cloudSiteId);
        }
    }
```

I am using below CXFConfiguration:-

```
@Primary
@Configuration("AttCXFConfiguration")
public class CXFConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private OpenstackAuth auth;
    @Autowired
    private HeatProxyRestImpl heatProxy;
    @Autowired
    private GlanceProxyImpl glanceProxy;
    @Autowired
    private NovaProxyImpl novaProxy;
    @Autowired
    private CinderProxyImpl cinderProxy;
    @Autowired
    private NeutronProxyImpl neutronProxy;
    @Autowired
    private CloudRegionRestV1 cloudRegionRestV1;
    @Autowired
    private JettisonStyleMapperProvider jettisonStyleObjectMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    @Autowired
    private SOAuditLogContainerFilter soAuditLogContainerFilter;
    @Autowired
    private HeatbridgeSynchronizerRest heatbridgeSynchronizerRest;

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean soapDispatcherServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("services");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServerHeatbridge() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(springBus());
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(heatbridgeSynchronizerRest));
        endpoint.setAddress("/heatbridge");
        endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new LoggingFeature()));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(jettisonStyleObjectMapper.getMapper()),
                soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper), soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        return endpoint.create();
    }


    // Uses normal Jackson marshalling semantics
    @Bean
    public Server rsServerApi() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(springBus());
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(cloudRegionRestV1));
        endpoint.setAddress("/api");
        endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new LoggingFeature()));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(jettisonStyleObjectMapper.getMapper()),
                soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper), soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer2() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(springBus());
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(heatProxy, glanceProxy, novaProxy, neutronProxy, cinderProxy));
        endpoint.setAddress("/proxy");
        endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(createSwaggerFeatureForProxy(), new LoggingFeature()));
        endpoint.setProvider(new ObjectMapperSingleton());
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(jettisonStyleObjectMapper.getMapper()),
                soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper), soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProvider(new OpenStackResponseExceptionMapper());
        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer3() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(springBus());
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(auth));
        endpoint.setAddress("/auth");
        endpoint.setProvider(new ObjectMapperSingleton());
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(jettisonStyleObjectMapper.getMapper()),
                soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper), soAuditLogContainerFilter));
        endpoint.setProvider(new OpenStackResponseExceptionMapper());
        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiFeature createSwaggerFeatureForProxy() {
        OpenApiFeature openAPIFeature = new OpenApiFeature();
        openAPIFeature.setScan(false);
        openAPIFeature.setUseContextBasedConfig(true);
        openAPIFeature.setResourceClasses(
                Stream.of("HeatProxyRestImpl", "GlanceProxyImpl").collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)));
        openAPIFeature.setPrettyPrint(true);
        openAPIFeature.setTitle("MSO Openstack Adapter Application");
        openAPIFeature.setDescription("This project supports requests to Openstack for Instantiation and Queries");
        openAPIFeature.setVersion("1.0.0");
        return openAPIFeature;
    }
}
```

ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body writer has been found for class com.woorea.openstack.heat.model.Resources, ContentType: application/json